# Obtaining the page number and line associated with an error in VeraPDF

Tags: java, spring-boot, pdf

I am developing a Java application that makes use of VeraPDF to analyze and validate a list of PDF files.

As expected, the result of this validation is a list of errors and issues. So far, everything is fine. The problem I encounter is that the end user wants more details about where these errors occur, at least the page in the PDF where the error takes place, and ideally, also the line.

Is there any straightforward way to obtain this information associated with each problem?

Answer (score 2):

PDF/A validation errors are not necessarily associated with a particular visual location in the PDF document as indicated in the above comments. VeraPDF identifies the location of the error via the error `context` property such as for example:

```
root/document[0]/metadata[0](3 0 obj PDMetadata)/XMPPackage[0]`
```

The context defines a path in the model built from the document. In the above example the error is in the document level metadata, which is represented by the XMP package in the PDF object number 3, generation number 0.

While this syntax does require certain knowledge of PDF internals, it uniquely identifies the place in PDF file (not just a visual location).

Another example is

```
root/document[0]/pages[0](6 0 obj PDPage)/contentStream[0](10 0 obj PDContentStream)/operators[4]/usedGlyphs[0](JAPTCA+AboriginalSerif JAPTCA+AboriginalSerif 0 0 0)
```

which identifies the location of the error as related to a `.notdef` character (character with code 0) in the font `AboriginalSerif` used in 4th operator (counting from 0) in the content stream of page 0 (normally shown as page 1 in the user interface).

To map this context to a visual representation of a PDF file (page and line) one needs a PDF viewer, which is not a part of veraPDF.